# Tag merge: 'employment' and 'foreign-employment'

Tags: discussion

I think in the scope of this SE site they mean almost the same, and there isn't any good reason to separate them.

Current questions:

- [employment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) (3 questions)
- [foreign-employment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-employment) (4 questions)

Comment: [tag:employment] should encompass [tag:foreign-employment]

Comment: I'd be more inclined to keep foreign-employment, as employment questions _not_ related to foreign employment are probably iffy at best as far as being on-topic goes :)

Comment: @TimPost: your comment made me wonder wheter we might need both of them. 'employment' would mean any questions regarding working in the country where you live (which would only be on-topic if you are living abroad) and 'foreign-employment' would mean working in a country you are not normally living (like cross-border workers or posted workers).

Comment: @SztupY Then the tag names should be different, and one of them should be something like [tag:cross-border-employment]. However, cross-border workers are not really expats, are they? (That's more a question of scope than of tags IMHO. Let's make the scope clear, and the necessary tags with arise easily.)

Comment: @tohecz: Cross-Border workers might face additional problems compared to locals (and sometimes also compared to "real" expats), so I'd say they are on-topic.

Comment: Ok, then I think we can have a use for two tags. None of them should be [tag:employment] though since that would be ambiguous.